# No sound from internal speakers in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, 15.10

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 version on my Asus V1jp. Everything works just fine, except the sound system.

There is no sound at all from the internal speakers. Sound from headphone seems to work but it is so low, choppy, crackling and hard to hear anything clearly. This is the case of both the 32bit and 64bit versions.

The sound device of my system is AD1986A.

What I have done is:

1. Uninstall and reinstall ALSA;
2. Play around the `alsamixer` options from `Terminal`;
3. Add `options snd-hda-intel model=xyz`to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file` with `xyz` being `auto`, `laptop`, `asus`, `3stack` or `laptop-eapd`;

But, none of the above helps.

I have read quite a few posts about "No sound on Ubuntu" and have also tried solutions proposed, but my sound problem persists.

Can anybody have any solutions or workarounds to this problem? Help highly appreciated.

**UPDATED:**
I have also tried [DKMS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS), but the problem remains.

Comment: Have you tried using Pulseaudio yet?

Comment: Yes, I have. Starting `pavucontrol` from Terminal and trying all its options bring no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Alsa.  It was present in 15.04 but has yet to be resolved.
google "no sound ubuntu 15.04"

I got a Realtek chipset / Intel HDA  and it's basically null under 15.10.

Good luck